# What is the minimum policy needed to update and deploy an Elastic Beanstalk app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I want to update and deploy a new version on Elastic Beanstalk from my continuous deployment system (Codeship) but also want to lock down the rights that the deployment user has.

What is the minimum set if rights needed?

Comment: I started to ask myself exactly the same question. I'm deploying a dockerized application to Beanstalk from bitbucket pipeline. I checked here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ExamplePolicies_AEB.html but it seems many unnecessary actions and resources are included in the policies.

Answer (score 3):

This IAM policy provides all necessary permissions to perform the "Upload and Deploy" function:

- for a new Application Version
- in a specified Elastic Beanstalk Environment.

Replace the following:

- Replace $REGION with the specific region, for example: us-east-1
- Replace $ACCOUNT with the account number (without dashes), for example: 123456789012
- Replace $APPLICATION with the specific application, for example: My Beanstalk Application
- Replace $ENVIRONMENT with the specific environment, for example: My Beanstalk Environment

Node: if you push logs to CloudWatch you will need additional policies.

---

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowAutoscalingSuspendAndResumeProcesses",
      "Action": [
        "autoscaling:SuspendProcesses",
        "autoscaling:ResumeProcesses"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowElasticBeanstalkValidateConfigurationSettings",
      "Action": [
        "elasticbeanstalk:ValidateConfigurationSettings"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:$REGION:$ACCOUNT:environment/$APPLICATION/$ENVIRONMENT"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "elasticbeanstalk:InApplication": [
            "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:$REGION:$ACCOUNT:application/$APPLICATION"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowS3PutAndDeleteObjectInProperBucket",
      "Action": [
        "s3:Put*",
        "s3:Delete*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-$REGION-$ACCOUNT/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowElasticBeanstalkCreateStorageLocation",
      "Action": [
        "elasticbeanstalk:CreateStorageLocation"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowElasticBeanstalkCreateApplicationVersion",
      "Action": [
        "elasticbeanstalk:CreateApplicationVersion"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:$REGION:$ACCOUNT:applicationversion/$APPLICATION/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "elasticbeanstalk:InApplication": [
            "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:$REGION:$ACCOUNT:application/$APPLICATION"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowElasticBeanstalkUpdateEnvironment",
      "Action": [
        "elasticbeanstalk:UpdateEnvironment"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:$REGION:$ACCOUNT:environment/$APPLICATION/$ENVIRONMENT"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "elasticbeanstalk:InApplication": [
            "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:$REGION:$ACCOUNT:application/$APPLICATION"
          ]
        },
        "StringLike": {
          "elasticbeanstalk:FromApplicationVersion": [
            "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:$REGION:$ACCOUNT:applicationversion/$APPLICATION/*"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowElasticBeanstalkReadOnlyAccess",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "elasticbeanstalk:Check*",
        "elasticbeanstalk:Describe*",
        "elasticbeanstalk:List*",
        "elasticbeanstalk:RequestEnvironmentInfo",
        "elasticbeanstalk:RetrieveEnvironmentInfo",
        "ec2:Describe*",
        "elasticloadbalancing:Describe*",
        "autoscaling:Describe*",
        "cloudwatch:Describe*",
        "cloudwatch:List*",
        "cloudwatch:Get*",
        "s3:Get*",
        "s3:List*",
        "sns:Get*",
        "sns:List*",
        "cloudformation:Describe*",
        "cloudformation:Get*",
        "cloudformation:List*",
        "cloudformation:Validate*",
        "cloudformation:Estimate*",
        "rds:Describe*",
        "sqs:Get*",
        "sqs:List*"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```